# How generic REST client can use O Auth access tokens while making requests to Resource Server?

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth-2.0

We are implementing generic REST client where in we want to support O' Auth 2.0. For now we are thinking off to allow users to define Access Token (no matter from where they bought it) while configuring client, which REST client will use while making requests.

is it possible ? I have couple of questions

1. Is the way a client get access token from authorization server a standard ?
2. Is client registered with the auth server while requesting access_token and can't same access token be used by other clients?
3. Is SSL or TSL mandate ?
4. Is the way client send access token to Resource server (while making resource req)a standard, does all Resource provider (facebook, linkedin, salesforce, google) support access_token sent in HTTP header or in Query parameter.
5. Is sending access token to resource server standardized, i.e. we need not to encrypt or use any third party lib for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you read the spec [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).
Every Library implementation uses this standard, you can use whatever method to generate your keys and authorizations etc, but if you conform to those interfaces then you should be fine.